# Copy files to custom sectors on HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, defragment

Whenever I try to copy huge amount of files on a NTFS drive, Windows always fragments the file. This is very annoying because I'll get a really slow transfer speed (~100KB/s for a 15GB file!), and then I have to use a defragmentation to defrag the file, which takes forever for these large files.

This got me thinking, is there anyway to tell Windows to copy the file directly in a section of the drive which I know is empty, and thus avoid copying a fragmented file in the first place?

I have used Windows default copier, TeraCopy, Robocopy and xcopy in the past but none were a solution to this problem.

[image: Windows fragmentation file copy]

Comment: The problem is the fragmentation of your free space. The standard Windows defragmenter optimises the used space, but often makes the free space even more defragmented in the process. There are other defragmenters which attempt to optimise both, with varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the job of a file system driver (`ntfs.sys` in your case) to abstract away the physical location of a file's blocks from an application accessing the file. This implies, that the choice of copy utility will not make much of a difference.

What **does** make a difference, especially with NTFS, is the free space percentage - and this is very low indeed in your example. Your results will be much better, if the FS is not filled over the 70% mark.

So, basically: Your fragmentation problem stems from a too full NTFS volume.

Comment: The fraggmentation problem is due to the low amount of free space, but it is not the cause, of the slow transfer speeds (unless it is a SSD).

Comment: The low transfer speed is most likely caused by the fragmentation, which in turn is caused by the fullness of the volume.

Comment: It seems the answers are of a mix opionion.  I am in the camp that transfer speeds are not going to effect a mechanical drive.  [Does the amount of available free disk space in Windows (XP only?) impact performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/128357/does-the-amount-of-available-free-disk-space-in-windows-xp-only-impact-perfor/128359#128359)

Comment: The degradation of speed with fragmentation on mechanical drives is not a matter of opinion, it is a fact - and it is also easy to understand, as the most expensive operation on a HDD (random seek) has to be done more often.

Comment: +1, but I have a question. If defrag programs are able to move data after they have been written to the disk, is it possible for a file copy software to determine the optimised location when copying? If not, how come defrag software work even when `ntfs.sys` does not give access? I'm a bit confused, and would like to know what happens in the process.

Comment: In newer versions of windows, the file system drivers have special APIs that expose the block structure and are explicitly modeled to facilitate defragmentation. These APIs also provide the necessary atomicities to make sure, a power outage during a defrag won't ruin the FS structure. But: Accessing the file (as a file) and accessing the block structure are orthogonal concepts.